# Firebase design for content for different platforms

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I’m using firebase for a website and mobile app.

The basic structure of my database is something like this

```
database
├── course
│   ├── course-intro
│   └── chapters
│       ├── chapter1
│       │   ├── title
│       │   ├── intro
│       │   └── content
│       ├── chapter2
│       └── chapter3
└── users
```

I want to put long articles in the content section of the chapters. The articles have subtitles, lists etc. I’m looking for the best way to store them.

How can I split/recognize titles, subtitles, lists, paragraphs, .. if I want one solution for my website and mobile app?

Should I use html tags and replace them on mobile apps or is there an another way to have one text with the same layout for different platforms?

Or should I use something else altogether?